# angular-datatables works locally but not in production

Tags: angular, production, angular-datatables, angular12

I added angular-datatables to my project and customised my table. It works perfectly served locally but when I put it on the production server all the customisations are gone - no scrollbars, no sorting options, no pagination etc. It looks to me like the library is missing on production. But it is in my angular.json. I ran ng build. What could the problem be?

Here is my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "pd-free-angularcli": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "chart.js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/img/cloadlogo.png",
              {
                "input": "./node_modules/@google/markerclustererplus/images",
                "glob": "*",
                "output": "/images"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/scss/cload-theme.scss",
              "./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
              "./node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "pd-free-angularcli:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "pd-free-angularcli:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "pd-free-angularcli:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
              "./node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
              "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
              "https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-show-password@1.2.1/dist/bootstrap-show-password.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/sass/cload-theme.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/img/favicon.png",
              "src/favicon.png"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "pd-free-angularcli-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "pd-free-angularcli:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "pd-free-angularcli",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Comment: what kind of error showing ? please remove one time rm -rf node/module and reinstall npm packages sudo npm i

Comment: ERROR TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    Angular 9
core.js:6456

Comment: it's funny really coz I'm not using angular 9. I'm using angular 12.

Comment: I've also somehow managed to reproduce this error locally and now cannot revolve it locally anymore. I reproduced it by changing the paths in scripts and styles (added or removed "./"). not sure which one exactly was making it work or not. oh dear.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it!

The problem was the **order** of the scripts.

It should be jQuery **FIRST**.